# Metasploit as a Daemon creator

Tags: metasploit

is using metasploit post exploit tools an easy way to create a "daemon"?

I mean I can just add my awesome.exe to the payload and migrate the payload to svchost.exe and it will persist on the machine

Is this scenario possible? I mean this will be done on a local computer which could be also monitored locally using the payload.

Please let me know if I'm just really confused or it's actually possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to gain persistence, metasploit uses some modules. Some create a registry key which starts the exe you want upon startup and some create services. A simple migration won't help, because upon next startup, svchost.exe will start as the original binary without your payload in memory.

Comment: So in order to fulfill my need I'll have to add to startup my awesome.exe with some injection code, i.e ```https://github.com/pwndizzle/c-sharp-memory-injection``` and inject into ```svchost.exe``` ONCE my awesome.exe initialized on Startup? Sounds like metasploit won't be assisting me today then, this could be done adding a couple of lines into my code, I see no reason to use metasploit anymore, or am I wrong?? Thought metasploit had the modules to perform this with payloads, or am I missing the scenario where you import your custom payload that has the code to perform this "special" things..

Comment: No, you are not injecting anything. awesome.exe will be running as a new service. In-memory injection works during runtime, if you reboot the system it's useless, unless you create a new .exe named svchost.exe with your payload pre-injected inside as code (see Shellter project). But still svchost.exe is a verified and signed executable, so you won't just be able to replace it, even with administrative privileges.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubts, I decided to use some code instead to do this and a little batch file, have a good one!